# Searchlogic Large Data Search

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I optimize the search of Searchlogic in a large data(3,000+ record)?

Im having trouble on searchlogic searching through Users that have 3,000 records and only search the name of the user.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you want to look how to optimise your database. You can create indexes for the searchable columns of your User model (the ones present in WHERE SQL clauses).
Also make sure you are not eager loading the objects and select only the needed columns instead of SELECT * clauses.